# How to change a HTML element by id?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a beginner question, I am following a javascript course, and it should work but it does not.

In my HTML page I have the following elements (done that way so the "x1=" and the number are on the same line):

```
<section id="results">
  Solutions
  <p></p>
  x1=<label id="x1">0</label>
  <p></p>
  x2=<label id="x2">0</label>
</section>
```

and in the javascript part I try to change these elements with the following code

```
document.getElementById("x1").value = x1;
document.getElementById("x2").value = x2;
```

but they do not change. I also do not see an error in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `.value = x1;` what is `x1` here?

Comment: It is a well defined number which I print to the console and verified it is a number, like e.g. -4.302775637731995 (float)

Comment: `<label>` elements don't have a `value` property. Maybe you meant to manipulate `<input>` elements?

Comment: Yes thats it! 'input' is my 'output'. It is somewhat confusing to name an output element input...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `<label>` does not have a `value` property. You have to either use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) or [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) like:

```
document.getElementById("x1").textContent = x1;
document.getElementById("x2").textContent = x2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `textContent` or `innerHTML`

```js
document.getElementById("x1").innerHTML = x1;
```

Comment: JS is case-sensitive: `innerHtml !== innerHTML`!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `value` property with `<label>`, use it on `<input>` for example. So, use `innerHTML` or `innerText` instead.

Here is your full code (with `innerHTML`):

```js
let x1 = 2;
let x2 = 5;

document.getElementById("x1").innerHTML = x1;
document.getElementById("x2").innerHTML = x2;
```

```html
<section id="results">
  Solutions
  <p></p>
  x1=<label id="x1">0</label>
  <p></p>
  x2=<label id="x2">0</label>
</section>
```

A living demo: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/abvLENr?editors=1010

And here is your code (with `innerText`):

```js
let x1 = 2;
let x2 = 5;

document.getElementById("x1").innerText = x1;
document.getElementById("x2").innerText = x2;
```

```html
<section id="results">
  Solutions
  <p></p>
  x1=<label id="x1">0</label>
  <p></p>
  x2=<label id="x2">0</label>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because `value` is an `<input>` property. To change a label text you must change it `innerText`. So, it will be be something like that:

```
document.getElementById("x1").innerText = x1;
```

If your string contains HTML, you can use `innerHTML` instead. Note that in your example we are expecting `x1` to be a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById("x1").setAttribute = "x1";
document.getElementById("#2").setAttribute = "x2";
```

also in

```js
document.getElementById("#2").setAttribute = "x2";
```

the id is "#2" but in HTML the id is "x2". Consider changing the

```js
document.getElementById("x1").setAttribute = "x1";
document.getElementById("#2").setAttribute = "x2";
```

to

```js
document.getElementById("x1").setAttribute = "x1";
document.getElementById("x2").setAttribute = "x2";
```